# How do I select the latest post for a user in a mysql DB?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following table setup:

table name `posts`

```
Id, user_id, title, content, date
```

Now i need to select the lastest(last) post of each user from above table
Can anyone help how can we do this?

right now i am using

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` GROUP BY `user_id`
ORDER BY `ID` asc
```

but actually it just fetches the first post of each user but i need the last post of each user

Comment: Instead of ORDER BY ID ASC use DESC..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okey this might be your problem do one thing

```
    SELECT * FROM 
   (SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY date desc) AS `result` 
    GROUP BY `result`.`user_id`
```

As group by user_id is used earlier your example it will take only the first id
check this it will work!

Comment: <vomit>. Selecting fields which are neither in the group by list nor an aggregate function (e.g., `max()`) is a weird thing that MySQL allows. You must only use it when *all rows have the same value*. See the MySQL docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html

Comment: The server is free to return any value from the group,but normally it does return only the first row.in that sense my query is correct.here in subquery it will order by date so that the latest post of all users will be available on the top.

Comment: Php: not my downvote, but I've seen queries like this break many times (on live installations and on the same versions of `MySQL`).

Answer (score 4):

Assuming posts are assigned in an increasing order:

```
SELECT max(post_id) AS post_id FROM posts GROUP BY user_id;
```

if no such assumption can be made, you can do something like:

```
SELECT user_id, max(date) AS most_recent FROM posts GROUP BY user_id
```

you can then use that to grab the full post:

```
SELECT p1.*
  FROM
    (SELECT max(post_id) AS post_id FROM posts GROUP BY user_id) p2
    JOIN p1 ON (p1.post_id = p2.post_id);
```

or for the no assumption case:

```
SELECT p1.*
  FROM
    (SELECT user_id, max(date) AS most_recent FROM posts GROUP BY user_id) p2
    JOIN p1 ON (p1.user_id = p2.user_id AND p2.most_recent = p1.date);
```

You will get multiple posts from a user if the most recent posts both have the same date. Arguably, that is correct, as neither is newer.

Note: These can be written as correlated subqueries as well. Benchmarking will tell you which perform best in your particular case.

Comment: you're suggesting to join ... by date? really? wow... Michael Widenius must be spinning in his own ... bed!

Comment: @Gonzalo Larralde: Would you like to point out an actual technical problem with a join on a date? (Personally, I'm more considered with Codd spinning than Monty.)

Comment: No, I would not point out an actual problem with a join while on a date with a pretty woman. It would kill the romance. ;) (Sorry -- I misread it the first time, and had to be a smart alek.)

Comment: sure, performance... and, please, don't tell me that you're going to make an index by user_id,date... don't make me <vomit> ;-)

Comment: @Gonzalo Larralde: Nothing wrong with an index on a datetime. I'd expect those to already exist when you're searching for most recent. Sometimes its even reasonable for a datetime to be part of the primary key. Indeed, what would your candidate keys be for a post table before introducing the post_id surrogate key?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  p.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT  user_id
        FROM    posts
        ) pd
JOIN    posts p
ON      p.id = 
        (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    posts pi
        WHERE   pi.user_id = pd.user_id
        ORDER BY
                user_id DESC, date DESC, id DEST
        LIMIT 1
        )
```

Create an index on `posts (user_id, date, id)` for this to work fast.

See examples `4` and `3` here:

- [**10 things in MySQL (that won’t work as expected)**](http://explainextended.com/2010/11/03/10-things-in-mysql-that-wont-work-as-expected/)

which explain why your original query will not work.

Answer (score -2):

Ok, this is ugly, but it works.

MySQL has a handy quirkable mode of group columns. In other DB engines, like MSSQL, if you're using `GROUP BY`, every column in `SELECT` must be grouped, or should be an aggregation function.

What MySQL does, actually, is bring up the first record used to group by. So, if you do this:

```
SELECT * FROM posts GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY ID desc
```

Should work. But, if it doesn't, it means that it first groups and ignores the order, so, you can try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM posts WHERE 1 = 1 ORDER BY ID desc) GROUP BY user_id
```

It's important to put you filters inside the subquery, in order to keep performance in acceptable levels.

Good luck!

Comment: No, it does not grab the first record. It grabs an arbitrary record. It may grab the first one today, but your next MySQL upgrade may change that. Or maybe it'll be different on your master vs. your slave (fun!). "When using this feature, all rows in each group should have the same values for the columns that are ommitted from the GROUP BY part. The server is **free to return any value** from the group, so the **results are indeterminate** unless all values are the same. " (emphasis added). http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html

Comment: you should work on Legal Dept. at Microsoft, hahaha. They're just covering their butts in case they may need change this in the future.. But the thing is that it actually returns always the first result in dataset, and it just work..

Comment: Obvious reasons to not return the first would include getting rid of the implicit sort which is part of group by, which would be a nice performance win (and remove the need to put weird `order by null` clauses after every `group by` that you don't need ordering and want performance), or implementing group by using hash indices, etc. I suppose if you want to write fragile code, ignoring the published behavior is a great way to do it. Maybe Quassnoi (who has seen it break according to his/her comment) can provide more tips!